# Redirecting React application with Nginx not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, nginx, redirect, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

> I'm encountering difficulties with redirecting my React application using Nginx. Despite configuring the redirects in the Nginx server block, the redirections are not occurring as expected and the React application running on fine Nginx.

**Specific Behavior:**

> Despite configuring Nginx for URL redirection, the redirections are not functioning as expected.

**Error Messages:**
22#22: *1 directory index of "/etc/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 10.4.2.0, server: 10.0.0.0, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "10.0.0.0:80"

I'm trying to redirect a react application using nginx server.
The configurations for both react application and nginx server are listed below.

My React Application is running in 3000 port.

```
├── docker-compose.yml
├── dockerfile
├── nginx.conf
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── logo192.png
│   ├── logo512.png
│   ├── manifest.json
│   └── robots.txt
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── App.css
    ├── App.js
    ├── App.test.js
    ├── index.css
    ├── index.js
    ├── logo.svg
    ├── reportWebVitals.js
    └── setupTests.js
```

My React Application is running in 3000 port.

and my dockerfile where the react application is running in 3000 port.
the configuration looks like this

```
#FROM node:15.0.0-alpine
FROM node:21.3-alpine as build

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app/build

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the container
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps

# Copy the entire application to the container
COPY . .

# Build the Vite application for production
RUN npm run build

# Use Nginx as the production server
FROM nginx:alpine

# Copy the built Vite app to Nginx's web server directory
# Adjust this line if your Vite project's output directory is different
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

# Copy custom Nginx configuration
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Fix permissions for Nginx
# This ensures Nginx has read access to all files and directories
RUN chmod -R 755 /usr/share/nginx/html && \
    chown -R nginx:nginx /usr/share/nginx/html

# Expose port 80 for the Nginx server
EXPOSE 80
# Start Nginx when the container runs
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**ngin.conf** file

```
 server {
    listen 80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    # Optionally, configure gzip compression to improve file loading for your SPA
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
}
```

Nginx is running in port 80
This is my nginx configuration folder structure.

```
├── docker-compose.yml
├── html
├── logs
│   ├── access.log
│   └── error.log
└── nginx.conf
```

**nginx.conf** configuration file looks like this:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    multi_accept        on;
    use                 epoll;
}

http {
    
    upstream firstapp {
        server 10.0.0.0:3000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 10.0.0.0;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location /firstapp {
            proxy_pass http://10.0.0.0:3000;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to acheive this:

> As the nginx server is running in 80 and react application is running in 3000 port.
> I tried to redirect a react application with nginx server.
> for example : If I give this url "http://10.0.0.0:80" it gives nginx server and then I added
> "http://10.0.0.0:80/firstapp" , so it should redirect to "http://10.0.0.0:3000"
> But this is not happening and I'm getting a error message.

**Error Message:**

> 22#22: *1 directory index of "/etc/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 10.4.2.0, server: 10.0.0.0, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "10.0.0.0:80"